# Derivative of $\sin(x)/x$ for $x\to0$ without using L'Hôpital's rule nor Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

this is my first question and it is about an exercise of calculus 1 I have seen at the University when I was an undergraduate. Till today I have not found the answer.

The exercise is the following:
calculate the derivative of $\sin(x)/x$ for $x \to 0$ without using neither L'Hôpital's rule nor Taylor expansion.

This leads to:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x)/x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x)-x}{x^2}$$

Using l'Hopital rule or Taylor expansion (or even drawing the function) is easy to see the result is 0 but I would be curious to see how to get it otherwise.
I have tried to use the squeeze theorem but without success so far.

Many thanks in advance to those who will provide insight here :-)

Comment: A well-known proof is using geometry and squeeze theorem. See, for ex., https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~lebed/Remarkable.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the limit to resemble the derivative in 0:

$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(0 + x) - \sin(0)}{x} = \sin'(0) = \cos(0) = 1.
$$

Comment: How do you prove that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$ ? Usually it's done using the limit you are trying to prove so it would be a circular reasoning.